# oracle pl: ref parameter in procedure how to

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, reference, procedure

I would like to check for each insert on a table that a specific value is unique.

employee_table is like:

```
employee_table(
  position varchar2,
  branch_ref ref branch scope is branch_table
);
```

There is only one "Head" position **per branch**. So there can be several 'Head' values in the column, that's why I can't use a unique constraint.

I cannot use triggers because of the 'table in mutation' error.

I decided to use a procedure to do my insert and validate the input.

However, one of the parameters is a ref to branch_table.

How can I pass a ref type parameter to a procedure ? I tried a lof stuffs that didn't work.

for example:

```
SELECT ref(b)
INTO br_ref
FROM branch_table
WHERE b.bid = 1;
/
EXECUTE proc_name('Head', br_ref);
```

Thank you

Comment: If I correctly understand, your goal is check just  'Head' value and do not allow duplicate this value  in `employee_table.position` column. another values may be repeated. Is this correct?

Comment: Why cannot you use constraints? How about `... CONSTRAINT c_unique_head CHECK (position <> 'Head')` ? You may need a 2-tiered approach handling the constraint violation from wherever you issue the insert/update to cater for the first record with `employee_table.position = 'Head'`.

Comment: No, to be more precise: there is only one 'Head' per branch. Attr branch_ref in employee table points to an object in branch_table. Makes sens that there is one 'Head' per branch. So to sum up: can have several 'Head' in the row, but only one per branch. I wanted to check it with a select count(*) from employee_table e where e.position = 'Head' and e.branch_ref = <the ref>. I edit my question.